# Can CodeFirst Membership Provider package used for MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a package in MVC 4 called

```
CodeFirst Membership Provider
```

Here is the link for it [CodeFirst Membership Provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/)

Can this be used for mvc5 as well? Or can it be modified to be used in mvc5 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right at the top of the page for the link you provided to [CodeFirst Membership Provider](https://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/).

> DEPRECATED!
>
> For new projects use the new Membership providers in ASP.NET MVC 5

I assume they are referring to ASP.NET Identity which was introduced in MVC 5, which technically is not a traditional provider at all.  This is a good thing. It also uses EF code-first and you can [learn about customizing it here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/customizing-aspnet-identity-in-mvc-5.html). The [SimpleSecurity Project](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) provides a wrapper around ASP.NET Identity that is similar to WebSecurity, which is the same approach taken by CodeFirst Membership Provider.